# Send jwt to API in request header from Reactjs frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jwt

I have a quick question. I am using Axios to send requests to the nodejs API, when I set the token in the request header the API returns "jwt must be provided". The API expects the token with a custom name attached to it - here's how far I've gotten.

Snippet of API code that sends the token on login:

```
const token = jwt.sign(
              {
                userID: result[0].userID,
                firstName: result[0].firstName,
                lastName: result[0].lastName,
                email: result[0].email,
                role: result[0].role,
                // exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60,
              },
              "HeyImaPrivateKeyyy"
            );
            res.json({ token });
            console.log("Login Attempt", res.statusMessage, req.body);
          } else {
            res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid credentials!" });
            console.log("Login Attempt", res.statusMessage, req.body);
          }
```

-- React code from here --

Response from API on successful login:

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySUQiOjEsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IkNhbWVyb24iLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IkVyYXNtdXMiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNhbWVyb25AY2xpZnRjb2xsZWdlLmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJzdXBlckFkbWluIiwiaWF0IjoxNjYzMzEzNTM2fQ.9R6vXn-5Vb5fj48eUJGPNUGnXMw9TXOjJCox7U36WMI"
}
```

Saving the token on successful login (React)

```
const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    const res = await api.post(
      "/auth",
      {
        email: email, //varEmail is a variable which holds the email
        password: password,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: false,
        },
      }
    );
    const { from } = state || {};

    let token = jwt(res.data.token);

    setToken("x-auth-token", token); // your token
    localStorage.setItem("x-auth-token", res.data.token);
    localStorage.setItem("userLogged", true);
    localStorage.setItem("name", token.firstName);
    localStorage.setItem("role", token.role);
    navigate("/auth/dashboard" || from.pathname, { replace: true });
  };
```

Here is the React component that is trying to call the API:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(null);

  const token = localStorage.getItem("x-auth-token");

  const studentCount = useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    };

    api.get("/students/", {}, config).then((response) => {
      setCount(response.data);
    });
  }, [token]);

  if (!count) return null;
```

This is what the API is expecting on request:

```
export const teacher = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
  if (!auth && !token)
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "Access denied." });

  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "DemoPrivateKey");
  if (auth && ["superAdmin", "admin", "teacher"].includes(decoded.role)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Access denied!" });
  }
};
```

Ideally, I would like to send the token as a header on successful login, but it saves as undefined on the client (have no idea how to fix that).

Comment: Could you please add what you get as response body from the login call?

Comment: You should consider using an `/lib/api.js` file where all your logic is (not in the component directly). So that all your components call a generic function that add the JWT retrieved from local storage. That would be more clean and easier to debug. Anyway, do you have the JWT stored in your local storage?

Comment: @XavierGarnier Yeah I'm planning on refactoring everything once I have the basic "skeleton" up. Yes, the token is stored in local storage (until I refactor)

Comment: Isn't it just that with axios, the headers parameters are set in second place not third. So that if `api.get()` is `axios.get()` then you should do `api.get("/students/", config)` instead of `api.get("/students/", {}, config)` as there is no data parameter in get method (compare to post method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Axios then, as per [the doc](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro), `get` method should have `config` parameter in second position not third one.
So maybe, simply updating `api.get("/students/", {}, config)` into `api.get("/students/", config)` should solve your issue.

Comment: Beautiful, the solution worked. Can't believe I didn't think of the fact that a get request wouldn't have a body... Thank you for pointing that out!